# Python 3.6 async aioodbc blocking

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-3.6, python-asyncio, pyodbc

I was hoping to use aioodbc with an async Semaphore to insert rows into a database. The below will write some rows into the destination database, but appears to lock up around Sempahore `value` +1. Any suggestion on how to rework this or address the block/contention?

Table definition:

```
create table async_testing (
    insert_id int null
)
```

Async Code:

```
import asyncio
import aioodbc

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def odbc_insert_worker(semaphore, value, conn):
    await semaphore.acquire()
    print("Acquire Semaphore")
    async with conn.cursor() as cur:
        await cur.execute('INSERT INTO async_testing VALUES (?)', value)
    print("Release Semaphore")
    semaphore.release()

async def db_main(loop, values):
    dsn="foo"

    values = list(values)
    db_semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(value=15)

    async with aioodbc.create_pool(dsn=dsn, loop=loop, autocommit=True) as pool:
        async with pool.acquire() as conn:
            tasks = [odbc_insert_worker(db_semaphore, value, conn) for value in values]
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

fmt_vals = range(0,1000)

loop.run_until_complete(db_main(loop, fmt_vals))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @jettify in the aiolibs channel this solution works:

```
import asyncio
import aioodbc
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def odbc_insert_worker(conn, value):
    async with conn.cursor() as cur:
        await cur.execute('insert into async_testing values (?)', value)

async def db_main(loop, values):
    dsn="foo"

    values = list(values)

    async with aioodbc.create_pool(dsn=dsn, loop=loop, executor=ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3), autocommit=True) as pool:
        tasks = [do_insert(pool, value) for value in values]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def do_insert(pool, value):
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        await odbc_insert_worker(conn, value)

fmt_vals = range(0,1000)

loop.run_until_complete(db_main(loop, fmt_vals))
```